# What is the use of entity's detach-method?

Tags: entity, entitymanager

At the moment, I'm learning more about ORM and entity states and lifecycles.
I understand what a detached entity is and how an entity can get into detached state.

However, one thing I really don't understand:
What is the use of the detach()-method offered by an entity-manager?

I mean it's one thing for an entity to become detached e.g. after serialization/deserialization.
But why would one want an entity to become detached by explicitly calling the detach()-Method?

Does anyone have some examples of usefull scenarios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It saves resources, so if you're going to have entities that are being used in a read only situation, you can detach them.